# guardar XML en base de datos sin crear el archivo

Tags: c#, xml

Buen día, hay manera que **dar formato XML a una lista de objetos y guardarla en una base de datos, sin necesidad de crear el archivo**, descargarlo y luego subir su contenido a la base de datos??
Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias deserializar el xml a clases que definas y mapeen con la estructura del xml

[Simple deserialization of XML to C#](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11)

Si tienes la clase que mapea con el xml solo debes usar

```
string xmlString = @"<Products>
                       <Product>
                          <Id>1</Id>
                          <Name>My XML product</Name>
                       </Product>
                       <Product>
                          <Id>2</Id>
                          <Name>My second product</Name>
                       </Product>
                     </Products>";

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
List<Product> productList = (List<Product>)serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

pero necesitas la clase

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

usas la clase

[XmlSerializer(Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_)